# SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator bcmail-jdk15on-158 compile error

Tags: java, email, encryption

I have upgrade my web project. Before I am using JDK 1.4. Now I am using JDK 1.7.
I have downloaded new jar due to the error "org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException: key inappropriate for algorithm.". It is bcmail-jdk15on-158.jar and bcprov-debug-jdk15on-158.jar. 
But now it has compile error as below screen. I really does not know how to solve. Is there any need to largely amend the code?

(1) The method addKeyTransRecipient(X509Certificate) is undefined for the type SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator

(2) Multiple markers at this line
    - The type org.bouncycastle.operator.OutputEncryptor cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
     required .class files
    - The method generate(MimeMessage, OutputEncryptor) from the type SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator refers to the 
     missing type OutputEncryptor

[Compile error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjGqW.png)

Comment: A) error messages are text so include them as formatted text in your question b) why are you not upgrading to Java 8? The process to go from 1.4 will be hard anyway - so why go with stuff that is already close to "outdated"?

Comment: Thx, it solved by amending the code to fit with the new jar functions.